# Deploy plugin when using Docker

Tags: graphdb

I'm wondering how I should deploy my custom plugin to GraphDB when using the DockerHub container. I found the /lib/plugins folder inside the container but how should I add a file here?

Adding files to the container is generally not a good idea I assume? Should we use a mount point for this? Of should be rebuild the image having the plugin inside?

Answer (score 0):

You can point to a specific directory for custom plugins - https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.1/plug-in-api.html#adding-external-plugins-to-graphdb

You need to mount the directory with the external plugins and pass the property "-Dgraphdb.extra.plugins=path_to_the_directory"